# Where to put collision handling in tile based game?

Tags: c++

Im currently developing a c++ console game.
The gam consist of a board class with a 2D array of tiles.

I also have game pieces classes for players, arrows, and items.

I need to be able to handle every collision between players/arrows/items, and im wondering between two possible solutions.

1) Hold a list on every tile that holds all the game pieces currently on that tile, and have an enterTile(gamePiece piece) on the tiles and put the logic there.

2) Have an outer "CollisionDetector" class that will scan all tiles/pieces for collision and handle them there.

What do you think?

Comment: Collision detection needs to be applied on move operations right? Where these are implemented/triggered?

Comment: Im still trying to decide that too. I belive that each movable object will have a move function..

Comment: I think version 1) is a good strategy as long only 1 tile can make a move at a time. Strategy 2) may be a good choice otherwise or as a more general design element, it can provide collision checks done using pieces' specific methods anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a function which would look like that:

```
void Object::OnCollision(Object collision_with); // "Object" is a generic type 
                                                 // of an object in the game
```

This function will handle the collisions.
In order to find the collisions, whenever an object enters a tile (enterTile), you can search that tile for the objects contained in it, and call their OnCollision functions.
That would of course mean keeping the items on the board as some list in their respective tile.

So I basically suggest your first solution.

Also notice, if your board is too big it might take more time to go through all of it. So in case it is rather large, consider the second solution you came up with.

Comment: I belive i'll go with that. (that being the first solution) and have like you said an colideWith() function and handle the logic in there. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

In my iOS game (which is not tile based but i think there might be some overlap) I have a collection detector class in the game loop that checks if actors are about to collide. If they are each actor is passed the other actor in a resolveCollisionWith(actor) method. This way each actor can decide how to respond to a collision with another actor and the CollisionDetector class does not have to know about the individual actors and their behavior.

Comment: Wouldnt that make you handle the same collision twice?

Comment: @DeaglinG Handling the collision twice is not necessarily wrong if some of the colliding pieces might rule over others (win a test). But for such case you might to check your collisions on a tile even ordered by 'precedence'.